# creating a list/array of items from select

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Background: I am using HTML/PHP/MySQL/ and Javascript if needed

What I have is a list of approximately 1000 people - I want to let the user select people, and then use the selected people to add them to a database.

I was thinking that each row of the table would have a unique link, and the link would either add that person to an array - or to some kind of list - and then at the end I can take that list and input it into the database..

I really want to have it that when somebody clicks a person's name - it automatically gets added to a list on lets say the left hand side - then once they are done, they can submit the list.

let me know if clarification is needed.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `<select multiple size=10>`

Comment: @u_mulder please elaborate ? - I see how that can select multiple - but can I set it up that the user doesn't have to hold shift/ctrl ?

Comment: Create `select` item with option `multiple`, it will allow to select a bunch of records to send to server,

Comment: No, you cant select items without control.

Comment: might not be user-friendly enough for the people I'm building this for ...

Comment: You use pagination to display list of people?

Comment: @Daniel just looked into it - probably a better solution than going through every record on one long page - however how can I select/add students

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with:

- Create page with space for smaller list on the left and list of people on the right.

Display people, with pagination, in table using something like this:

```
<table id="people">
    <tr>
        <td id="<?php echo $person['id']; ?>"><?php echo $person['name']; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When someone clicks on tr javascript code is executed to send post request with id the person.  PHP file responsible for handling this stores the id in the `$_SESSION['selectedPeople']` array or removes it from there if it is present. Also, when you click on td, `.selected` class is toggled and list of selected people on the left side is updated(for example, via getting JSON from PHP file and processing it to display in the table).

- you can press submit at any time. It would:

a) take you to the other page and submit the list(you have `$_SESSION['selectedPeople']` variable)
b) send an ajax call to page which will process `$_SESSION['selectedPeople']`

**Some code:**

selectHandler.php:

```
<?php
if($_POST && isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $id = (int)$_POST['id'];
    $action = '';
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['selectedPeople'])) {
        $_SESSION['selectedPeople'] = array($id);
        $action = 'added';
    } else {
        if(in_array($id, $_SESSION['selectedPeople'])) {
            $_SESSION['selectedPeople'] = array_diff($my_array, array($id));
            $action = 'removed';
        } else {
            $_SESSION['selectedPeople'][] = $id;
            $action = 'added';
        }
    }
    echo json_encode(array('action' => $action));
}
?>
```

Javascript(+[JQuery](http://jquery.com)):

```
$(function () {
    $('#people tr').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).children('td[id]').attr('id');
        $.post("selectHandler.php", { id: id })
            .done(function( data ) {
                if(data.action == "added") {
                    $(this).addClass('selected');
                } else if(data.action == "removed") {
                    $(this).removeClass('selected');
                } else {
                    alert('Some kind of error.');
                }
            }, "json");
        refreshSelectedList();
    });
});
```

I hope you get the idea.